# Erro ao resolver nome de host com Guzzle via cURL

Tags: php, laravel, libcurl, guzzle

Ao utilizar Laravel 8.38 e o Guzzle 7 nas últimas três semanas estamos tendo falhas repetidamente nos jobs com a seguinte saída:

```
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host
cURL error 6: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
```

a chamada é feita da seguinte forma:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

try {
        $response = Http::withOptions([
            'debug' => true,
        ])->retry(3)->post($url, $data);

        $content = $response->getBody()?->getContents() ?? null;

        if ($response->getStatusCode() != 200 || ! json_decode($content)->message) {
            throw new Exception('webhook notification fail', 400);
        }
        ...
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        ...
    }
```

como ao falhar o job ele vai para fila de failed jobs, reprocessamos eles e eles funcionam. Notamos que ao reiniciar o serviço do supervisor a taxa de erros diminui, mas continua ocorrendo.

Contextualizando, nesse cenário as requisições são feitas sempre de um serviço X para o mesmo endpoint, logo o host existe e é válido, tanto que ele funciona quando reprocessamos.

Alguma dica de como melhorar essa investigação ou resolver o problema?

Comment: Acredito que o problema possa ter relação com a resolução do DNS.
Você está fazendo essa chamada utilizando o DNS do host? Se sim, tente fazer com um nome interno para não precisar usar a internet para essa resolução, vai ficar mais rápido e resolverá. Se você já está utilizando um nome interno, isso está em container? É docker swarm? Kubernetes?

Comment: Tive  problemas bem parecidos após 29-09-2021. Veja isso  https://www.xlabs.com.br/blog/um-dos-primeiros-certificados-ssl-expira-amanha/ e https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/
No meu caso, esses erros acontecem ao acessar uma api de terceiros. Obs. Não estou afirmando que seja a causa do seu problema :)

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários, eu faço a chamada de um EC2, já utilizei o recurso de dnsmasq https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dns-resolution-failures-ec2-linux/ mas não surtiu efeito, a chamada é entre regiões e vou tentar fazer um vpc peering para nao depender da web, mas isso vai demorar por causa da complexidade da infra atual.